# How can I convert multi decimal point value to Int in easiest way?

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-point, integer, numbers

As we know that we can convert any float or decimal point value to Integer value simply by using `.toInt()` method.

But It converts 11.22 to 11 and 11.66 to 12 as I am doing ROUND.

This is absolutely fine.

But I have need of converting multi decimal value such as **0.1.1.12** to **0**
0r **11.0.3.3** to **11**.

In this case `toInt()`giving **NumberFormatException**

**How can I convert multi decimal point value to Int in easiest way ?**

Comment: I'm new to Kotlin but I hear about multi decimal for the first time.  I know that IPv4 has that format, but dot representation of it is normaly a string which means split the string where the dots are and then the first field `[0]` of returned array contains the number and you can call `toInt()` on it

Answer (score 1):

That then would be a string and you should probably split it by finding the first dot and then converting the result at the [0] index to a int.